# fs write to csv not writing with a for loop

Tags: javascript, csv, for-loop, export-to-csv, fs

I have my function below that runs an yelp API call and loops for the Json objects.  What i want to do is to write the JSON objects into a csv file.  However, when i write .....  it does not write it.  Below is my function.   I have the const require for fs.

```
 function fetchYelp(data) {

        /*Variables created to pass in to API GET request for Yelp */
        let orgName = data.OrgName;
        let city = data.City;
        let state = data.State;
        let zipCode = data.ZipPostal;
          let url = 'https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?';
                  let token = 'kuXTEkQCnyyj-5mbxUP73k0Q6dxLJa5go9S--AdW7h__922IUzTFR1GWAI-j4yALhcKdu1ac2oyhoMy9agoNlg0uFH3kJ9_zTqvamcikErzSSkb_ix0CRcPVOHZ9XHYx';

                  /*AXIOS GET API CALL URL */
                      axios.get(url+'term='+orgName +'&location='+city + state + zipCode,{
                        headers: {
                          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
                        }
                      })
                      /*If results are less than 1, moves on to fetchWhitePages API, ELSE, passes in the data*/
                          .then(res => {
                            if(res.data.businesses.length < 1){
                               fetchWhitePages(data);
                            }else{
                              console.log('RUNNING YELPAPI');

                                /*For loop to get JSON objects within YelpAPI */
                                for(let i =0; i < res.data.businesses.length; i++ ){
                                    console.log(res.data.businesses[i].name);

                        console.log(res.data.businesses[i].location.address1);
                                    console.log(res.data.businesses[i].phone);
                                    console.log('          ');
                                      fastcsv  
                                        .write(i)
                                        .pipe(ws);
                                }
                            }
                          })
                          .catch(err => {
                            console.log(err)
                          })
    }
```